# Some sites only fully load after refresh

Tags: firefox, website

When I try to enter some sites (such as this one) the browser loads the title (you can see "Super User" in the title (without the icon)) and just keep loading non stop until I hit the refresh button and the site load instantly.

I don't know what cause the problem but it started a few weeks ago thought it would pass but it hasn't.

Tried to restart router but the problem still remained.

What could cause this problem?

for better understanding:

1. I type in an address of any site (**some works perfectly some wont**).
2. The browser load only the title without the icon.
3. I hit refresh and the site load perfectly and instantly.

Again, not all sites does that, some works just fine but most wont.

(My browser is Firefox 36.0.4)

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your router? If you're running on wifi, wire up & try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue with JavaScript, could be an issue with a plugin. Could be the ISP... Your local connection.

I suspect the issue is your browser, not the websites. This can be tested by using a different browser!

**Update**

As per OP's comments, since it is fine in another browser, the issue is likely a plugin or the profile.

You could reset your profile, uninstall/re-install Firefox or remove all the plugins. Now, people will advise to disable but I have had experience where disabling doe3sn't disable as well as you'd like and some issues persist. I suggest you totally remove the plugins (noting you'll remove any preferences you once had)